# How to add draft editor with emojis in react?

Tags: reactjs, emoji, draftjs

I want to add toolbar which users can edit text and add emoji, is there a good package or library which I can use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use emojis with `Draft.js`

for further information visit [documentation](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/emoji)